# Tightening sequence, is the pattern crucial when going from inside out?

Tags: fastener, torque-specification

I know the importance of tightening in a star pattern/from inside out, but there could be more than one pattern and it has me overthinking a bit.

For example I’ve included two pictures with two different patterns going from inside out.

Which would be the best way or does it not matter as long as you keep alternating?

Pattern 1:
[image]

Pattern 2:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pattern 1 is better as it is more side to side taking turns.

Comment: Is that the pattern to always take?

Comment: @ohmmy - I'm thinking there's a lot of opinion in the basis of the question, which means you're going to get a lot of opinion as to answers. Basically, the idea of "inside out" is a good one. If a repair manual doesn't give you specifics as to the tightening sequence (or you cannot find any kind of reference), *generally* tightening from the inside out is a good idea, but you'd not have to do it exactly the same way to achieve desired results.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thanks that helps. So if there’s no reference then follow the inside out pattern in the 1st pic I posted or won’t matter “exactly” as long as I’m alternating sides

Comment: @ohmmy - That is the way I'd do it. I'm hoping Solar would agree, which is why I posted this as a comment and not a new answer.

Comment: What does the manufacturer say?